# Does sexual activity burn a significant amount of calories?

Tags: medical-science, physiology, sexuality, physical-fitness

Are there any reviews out there of scientific studies conforming or invalidating the common claim that sexual activity is a good way to burn calories? Have quantitative measurements of work exerted (i.e., energy spent) during sex ever been undertaken?

---

I can imagine that the popularity of this idea has lead to some testing over the ages, but use of the scientific method might have been impeded as

1. it was a rather taboo topic until
   the sexual revolution
2. there are so many variables involved (type of sexual activity,
   just to name one).

I tried some research myself, but generic web search engines for such keywords are overloaded by content of a, let's say, totally unacademic type.

Comment: Well, you're not not going to burn calories. And it's good. My review confirms the claim. :)

Comment: I didn't add this to the question, as it seems obvious: if someone knows of a study looking for participants, I might be convinced to enroll :)

Comment: good way compared to what though.

Comment: @Andy: once you have decided on a quantifier (a measurable quantity), you can compare it to anything you want: rest, slow walk, jogging, … I've edited the question to mention quantitative measurements.

Comment: Doesn't it depend entirely on *how* you do it?

Comment: When I do it, I usually just lie there and eat marshmallows.

Comment: I imagine there's a distinction between sexual activity and the effects on the human body. Men probably have to produce more sperm when sexually active, and women may become pregnant. The proximity to the claim of burning calories because of pregnancy is a bit of a stretch, but the claim that men must produce more sperm seems relevant. Also relevant may be the relative changes in sexual hormones i.e. testosterone (low amounts linked to excessive weight) and estrogen (high amounts linked to excessive weight), though those are probably correlative rather than causal.

Answer (score 20):

From "[Clinical Journal of Sport Medicine](http://journals.lww.com/cjsportsmed/Fulltext/2000/10000/Does_Sex_the_Night_Before_Competition_Decrease.1.aspx?WT.mc_id=HPxADx20100319xMP): October 2000 - Volume 10 - Issue 4 - pp 233-234"

> Considering that normal sexual intercourse between married partners expends only 25-50 calories (kCal)(the energy equivalent of walking up two flights of stairs),<sup>6</sup> it is doubtful that sex the previous night would affect laboratory physiological performance tests.

From "Jeremy Brecher - [Sex, Stress, and Health](http://baywood.metapress.com/app/home/contribution.asp?referrer=parent&backto=issue,4,6;journal,138,162;linkingpublicationresults,1:300313,1) - International Journal of Health Services, 1977 - Baywood"

> Each partner uses approximately 100 calories (kCal)

From "[Better Sex Through Exercise](http://clearblucreative.com/centerforsexualhealthstl/PDF/BetterSexFINAL.pdf)", by Cathy K. Naughton, MD:

> Sex may be considered a type of physical activity. Indeed, a 180 pound (82 Kg) individual burns approximately 120 calories (kCal) engaging in one hour of sexual activity using vigorous effort;
>   burns 100 calories (kCal) using moderate effort; and burns 80 calories (kCal) kissing and hugging. The
>   physical exertion required for sexual activity and therefore, calories burned may vary
>   widely among individuals [Cited: DeBusk RF.: Am J Cardiol 86 (Suppl 1): 51F-56F, 2000.].

---

P.S. A less scholarly but more fun read is *[The dieter's guide to weight loss during sex](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=x3eMlB0EGCsC&oi=fnd&pg=PA7&dq=%22sexual%20activity%22%20calories%20burn&ots=wwavqWxjO8&sig=uGzSW9yiZHB7i2hZ_n_Rm6U-d9U#v=onepage&q=%22sexual%20activity%22%20calories%20burn&f=false)* by Richard Smith.

Comment: You might want to check "Sex before competition" by Mirkin G, which is referenced in your quote.

Comment: Since there are different measurings used by physics and nutrition experts, and between the US and Europe, where a Kcal here is refered to as a Calorie there, can you please clarify which measurement you use and cite? 1g of Noodles is 3.5 kcal - I can't imagine that I need to have sex 35 times to burn a single noodle (except my own one).

Comment: Note that 1 kcal = 1 Cal = 1000 cal (note the different capitalization). 1 cal (small calorie) is the energy needed to increase the temperature of 1g of water by 1°C. 1 Cal (large cal, or kcal) is the energy needed to increase by 1°C the temperature of 1kg of water. Anyway, the SI unit for energy is the Joule (J) so that is what should really be used.